# Encoding iterations in bat file

Tags: encoding, cmd

Im using simple bat file to split CSV file into smaller ones.
I manually set encoding to 1250 before using this bat. 
And during second iteration (split) the file is not encoded in 1250 anymore.

Unfortunately I cannot use any tool or permanently reset encoding on my laptop, because it is company one.

How can I achieve, that all of the files have the same 1250 encoding?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a i = 1, j = %2
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%1) do 
(
echo %%a>>!i!_%1
set /a j -= 1
if !j! EQU 0 set /a i += 1, j = %2
)
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Add `chcp 1250` line just before `for` loop. Please [edit] the question to show a [mcve] (in particular, a sample `csv` file and consequent split ones).